# Migrating for Json4S to Circe

Tags: scala, circe

I have the following code written in json4s which compiles and works fine

```
import org.json4s._
def jsonRead[T <: AnyRef](input: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    Try(read[T](input)).get
}

def jsonWrite[T <: AnyRef](input: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): String = {
    write[T](input).toString
}
```

I have written the following Circe code

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser.decode
def unmarshall[T <: AnyRef](input: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) : T ={
    decode[T](input).right.get
}
def marshall[T <: AnyRef](input: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) : String = {
    input.asJson.toString
}
```

But I get the error

```
Error:(27, 16) could not find implicit value for parameter decoder: io.circe.Decoder[T] decode[T](json).right.get
Error:(27, 16) not enough arguments for method decode: (implicit decoder: io.circe.Decoder[T])Either[io.circe.Error,T]. Unspecified value parameter decoder. decode[T](json).right.get
Error:(30, 11) could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[T] obj.asJson.toString
Error:(30, 11) not enough arguments for method asJson: (implicit encoder: io.circe.Encoder[T])io.circe.Json. Unspecified value parameter encoder.    obj.asJson.toString
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`json4s` and `circe` are different libraries that work in different ways and that's why you can't use the same technique. While `json4s` `read` needs a Manifest to extract a value from Json, `circe` requires an instance of the typeclass `Decoder`. If you want to use `circe` in your example you should write something like

```
def unmarshall[T <: AnyRef](input: String)(implicit d: Decoder[T]) : T = {
    decode[T](input).right.get
}
def marshall[T <: AnyRef](input: T)(implicit e: Encoder[T]) : String = {
    input.asJson.toString
}
```

To understand the differences I suggest to read both implementation, they are very useful to understand how the two libraries do what they do. You can see the differences already in the signatures of json4s native [`read`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/0b28498f065ed8365e4e336a5fec1ec5d4e15649/native/src/main/scala/org/json4s/native/Serialization.scala#L70) and circe [`decode`](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Parser.scala#L24). I will copy here the important bits of the signatures to explain the fundamental difference between the two libraries. The signature of json4s native [`read`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/0b28498f065ed8365e4e336a5fec1ec5d4e15649/native/src/main/scala/org/json4s/native/Serialization.scala#L70) is

```
def read[A](input: String)(implicit mf: Manifest[A]): A
```

which can be interpreted as "I can convert a String into any type A if you provide a Scala Manifest for it". Because [`Manifest`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/933bab29ecd8a9ec23e14cc37db9c4cdd666e34f/src/library/scala/reflect/Manifest.scala#L44) is a Scala trait used for reflection, you can deduce that `read` will use reflection.

The signature of circe [`decode`](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Parser.scala#L24) is different:

```
def decode[A](input: String)(implicit d: Decoder[A]): Either[Error, A]
```

which can be read as "I can try to convert a String into a type A if you provide a circe Decode instance for it". The [`Decoder`](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Decoder.scala#L12) typeclass just tells the system how to decode a value of type `A` from json.